# Why did we take gradient outside the integral sign in Scalar potential derivation?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, vector-fields, calculus

[image][image]

I tried to understand the reasoning given in it but I couldn't understand it. It says that **"as the gradient operation involves x and not the integration variable x', it can be taken outside the integral sign".**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially using [Leibinz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

$$
{\displaystyle {\frac {{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}}\left(\int _{a}^{b}f(x,x')\,{\rm d}x'\right)=\int _{a}^{b}{\frac {\partial }{\partial x}}f(x,x')\,{\rm d}x'.}
$$

Comment: I know this but what does the statement mean that it does not involve integration variable x'?

Comment: @HaaranAjgaonkar It means that you are integrating w.r.t $x'$, but taking the derivative w.r.t $x$, so the rule above applies

Comment: Thank you very much, I was a little bit confused by the language of the context.